# Extract single frame with MDAnalysis

Tags: python, pdb, gromacs

How can I do to extract a single frame as a pdb file from a trajectory traj.xtc file, by using MDAnalysis?

I've got a universe
u=mda.Universe('confout.gro','traj.xtc')

Then I selected a residue by doing select_atoms, and I would like to extract a single frame as a pdb file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Q to more involved folk in admin: why was Community bot was invoked for this, as it was a case of nobody bothering to answer because it is a boring 'please link me to command X in the documentation' request. I.e. https://docs.mdanalysis.org/stable/documentation_pages/coordinates/init.html#writers

Answer (score 1):

Check out gmx_trjconv - this command is in GROMACS and accepts several options where you can specify the specific single frame that you want to output/write - out to the new pdb/gro/xtc file.  https://manual.gromacs.org/current/onlinehelp/gmx-trjconv.html